# Mongo optimisation: query performance vs database structure

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, optimization, data-structures

Context: a NodeJs (meteorjs) app connected to a MongoDB 4.0 server

I have a set of data I am computing quite often and that I need to store oevr time and then access to a particular set of data from my app. The set is an array of 12 000 objects, which final weight is about 3MB (measured by using MongoDB collection statistics on a Collection with only one set of data: size : 3,3MB; count : 12964). It is related to some computation parameters. I need to retrieve the set using a query.

I have to choose between two database structures:

**Option 1:**
One collection storing computation references with an ID (let's name it `ReferenceCollection`), and one other collection with all the 12000 objects per computation stored as single documents and a referenceId pointing to the ID created before.

Here is a schematic representation:

```
ReferenceCollection :
|--- _id: ObjectId("a")
|--- computation : "my reference"

ResultCollection : 
|--- _id: ObjectId("b")
|--- referenceId : ObjectId("a")
|--- fieldResut1 : data
.
.
|--- fieldResut20 : data
```

To retrieve the set, I would query for the referenceId in the first collection using computation parameters), then query the second one with the reference Id to get the 12 000 documents.

```
let reference = ReferenceCollection.findOne({computation: "my reference"}) // this is lightweight
let results = ResultCollection.find({referenceId: reference._id}) // this search for the 12 000 results
```

**Option 2:**
A single collection storing computation references with a key containing an array with the data inside

Here is a schematic representation:

```
ResultCollection : 
|--- _id: ObjectId("b")
|--- computation : "my reference"
|--- result : Array(    
    |--- fieldResut1 : data
    .
    .
    |--- fieldResut20 : data
)
```

To retrieve the set, I would do only one query with my computation parameters to get a single document containing all my data.

**Problem:**
I am experiencing performance issues with the first option: querying and retreiving all 12000 documents from a MongoDB  desktop client (studio 3T) is quite slow: 3 seconds in my setup. The second option takes only 1 second to retrieve (these times include download of the data). It causes my app to wait a lot while getting the data.

Querying from mongoshell on the server is very fast when returning cursors (about 20ms for option 1).

---

Can you confirm that option 2 is the good choice to store this data?

Do I have any other choices regarding data structure?

I am running MongoDB on a single node. Do you think that setting a replica set could help to improve the read performance?

Comment: "MongoDB 4.0 connected to a NodeJs" - it's other way round. "which final weight is about 3Mo" - what unit you are using to weight?  "two database structures" - explanations are a bit messy, an example of documents and queries would significantly increase chances to get an answer. "is quite slow" - do you `$lookup` or `.forEach` it?  "is very fast" - do you retrieve all documents or just a cursor? "setting a replica set could help to improve the read performance" - definitely not.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I have taken into account your remarks and edited my post. Regarding "quite slow" => it's when querying and retreiving all data to display it, I guess like the `.toArray()` function. Regarding "very fast", it's a cursor. Can you detail why a replica set won't increase read performance ? In my mind a replica set would allow parallelizing reads and hence more performance. Thanks

Comment: Does `3,3Mo` means 3.3MB?  Collection stats returns size of data in bytes with scale of 1 by default. Size is critical for option 2. If I understand you want to embed  12,000 documents x 20 fields each. Size of a single document in mongodb is limited to 16 MB, including field names + negligible overhead. If you "data" is something like a number or a string of few bytes, it kinda fits into 3.3 MB. In this case you are losing time somewhere outside of the db - network, app, etc. Changes in document structure won't help

Comment: You have an index on `ResultCollection.referenceId`, don't you?

Comment: Yes, 3,3MB is what I meant, sorry. `ResultCollection.referenceId` is indexed. I think document structure has an impact because I am seeing huge differences in performances (1second vs 3 : it is a lot). Of course network causes delay, but here the download time of the two structures should be the same.

Comment: check what [.exaplin()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#db.collection.explain) says. As a rule of thumb the embedded docs gives better read performance but on the 3.3 MB database I wouldn't expect much difference, and in any case it should be way less than a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll probably find in this scenario is the difference is mostly due to having to do two connections / queries which is mostly related to your network.

Option 1 you would use if, for example, a collection of users that are referenced in a collection of transactions.

The idea is that if you need to connect two collections, you only do it if the connecting collection is going to be referenced multiple times and has complex documents.

If it's simply to have a collection of names that are then referenced in another collection, then it's wrong.

If you need to connect two Mongo collections, consider using an aggregation so that the Mongo server can get the data in 1 hit compared to needing to do multiple queries.

EDIT:

To give you an idea on performance, the first option as it is right now would take twice as long purely because it has to connect twice. If the same query happens a lot, then you'll really see a performance hit for no gain (unless the "computation" field changes a lot, then that might justify it). If you're using an aggregation, then you won't really see any performance loss as it's considered a single connection.

Option two is just a single lookup and then the time it takes to return the array data. So in most cases the same as option 1 while using an aggregation.

Also consider the array might be a bottleneck if it consists of complex objects. Ideally you would avoid an array and flatten it out into single documents with fields. That way when you do a query, you can set what fields to return, thus not returning fields that aren't needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it confirms that option 2 is the good theoretical choice for my data (no need to link this data to other things). Can you add some insight on query performance for my two use cases ?

Comment: Updated my answer. The best way to know for sure is to load both options up with 50, maybe 100,000 documents and then do a repeat query on both for a couple of thousand queries and see which finishes first. The main rule is to keep it simple and return only the data you need. Both these rules should reduce server load and data transfer which obviously reduces wait time. EDIT: also keep in mind multiple users using it and the potential CPU usage complex queries can cause.